# TypeScript: The object properties in the array are interdependent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The object properties in the array are interdependent
eg when call AComponent

I want componentProps must be Type1Props, when `items.type === 'type1'`，
if `items.type === 'type2'` componentProps shoud be Type2Props

```
//I want componentProps must be Type1Props, when ` items.type === 'type1' `， if `items.type === 'type2'` componentProps shoud be Type2Props
<AComponent items= {[
{type:'type1', componentProps{  }}
{type:'type2', componentProps{  }
]}>
```

Below is AComponent.tsx code

```
// if type === type1 the value must be constraint with Type1Props
type ComTypes = {
   type1 : Type1Props,
   type2 : Type1Props,
   type2 : Type1Props,
}

type ItemType =
    'type1'
    | 'type2'
    | 'type3'
  

//  The object properties in the array
type ItemProps<T> = {
    type: T
    componentProps: ComTypes[T]
    showItem?: boolean
}

interface Props extends FormProps {
    itemsArray: QDItemProps[]
}

const AComponent: FC<Props> = ({itemsArray}) => {

}
export default AComponent
```

I do not know how to solove this scene

Comment: I think if you use an enum for Comtypes that could solve your problem? or I might need more explanation to understand what your goal is here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union types to do this. I'll give you a more generic example that is not using react, for the benefit of others who may stumble upon this question.

```js
type Type1Props = "A";
type Type2Props = "B";
type Type3Props = "C";

type PropTypes =
  | {
      type: "type1",
      componentProps: Type1Props,
    }
  | {
      type: "type2",
      componentProps: Type2Props,
    }
  | {
      type: "type3",
      componentProps: Type3Props,
    };

const p1: PropTypes = {
  type: "type1",
  componentProps: "A",
};

const p2: PropTypes = {
  type: "type2",
  componentProps: "B",
};
```

You should be able to extend this for your use case.

Comment: but i have more than 10 types